# Can you have XSL variables in the document() function?

Tags: xml, xslt

This works just fine:

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="issue_info_file" 
     select="document('/issues/2010/12/08/info.xml')
                /page-components/issue-metadata-component/title"/>
```

But this does not:

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="issue_info_file" 
     select="string(concat($full_issue_path,'/info.xml'))"/>
<xsl:variable 
     name="issue_title" 
     select="document($issue_info_file)
                /page-components/issue-metadata-component/title"/>
```

Does anyone if this is even allowed in XSLT? If not, does anyone recommend a solution for opening files with a dynamic variable?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work, unless your `$full_issue_path` variable contains the wrong value of course. Can you print the value of `$issue_info_file` in the output to see what it evaluates to?

Comment: Using variables as arguments of the `document()` function is perfectly OK, provided the values of the arguments are of the type expected (such as a URI). Most probably the value of `$full_issue_path` when concatenated with '/info.xml' does not produce a valid URI or the correct URI. You need to provide a complete example if you hope people to uncover your error.

Comment: From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document : *If the second argument is omitted, then it defaults to the node in the stylesheet that contains the expression that includes the call to the document function* It means that if you use `fn:document( $string-data-type )`, a relative URI will be resolved against your stylesheet URI (that might be not present, or some URI scheme not supported like embbeded files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you have XSL variables in the
>   document() function?

**Yes**.

Using variables as arguments of the `document()` function is perfectly OK, provided the values of the arguments are of the type expected (such as a URI). Most probably the value of `$full_issue_path` when concatenated with `'/info.xml'` does not produce a valid URI or the correct URI.

**You need to provide a complete example** if you hope people to uncover your error.

Comment: Turns out the $full_issue_path was incorrect. Once corrected it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know if this issue is still open, but there does not seem to be an answer. I have this code working in my XSL file.

```
<xsl:variable name="docRoot">../sitemap/</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="fullDocRoot" select="string(concat($docRoot,'sitemap.xml'))"/>
<xsl:for-each select="document($fullDocRoot)/root/sitemap/loc">
```

Hope that helps someone.