# Using xsl:variable in as part of document path

Tags: xml, xslt

Because of changing directories I need to use a variable in my document() path file

```
<xsl:variable name="topicdir" select="(tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()-1])"/>
<xsl:variable name="mapTitle" select="(document('../bin/out/index.ditamap'))//title"/>
```

Instead of 'out' I need $topicdir there. How do I concatenate this? I can't seem to get it to work...

Thanks in advance!
Sander

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have XSL variables in the document() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784495/can-you-have-xsl-variables-in-the-document-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<xsl:variable name="mapTitle" select="(document(concat('../bin/', $topicdir, '/index.ditamap')))//title"/>
```

Or maybe this to avoid too many nested functions

```
<xsl:variable name="docName" select="concat('../bin/', $topicdir, '/index.ditamap')" />
<xsl:variable name="mapTitle" select="(document($docName))//title"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your version seems to work beautifully, While trying _concat_ myself I think I messed up a few single and double quotations. I'll take your second suggestion in the futute!